# Enabling LINQ for BindingListView<T>

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

[Andrew Davies](http://aboutcode.net/) created an excellent little class on [sourceforge](http://blw.sourceforge.net/) called `BindingListView<T>` which essentially allows you to bind a collection to a `DataGridView` while supporting sorting and filtering.  Binding a `DataGridView` to a normal `List<T>` does not support sorting and filtering, as the proper interfaces are not implemented by `List<T>`.

The class works great and has solved my UI problems.  However, it'd be awesome if I could iterate through the collection using LINQ, but I'm just not sure how to set it up to do so.  Source code can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blw/files/BindingListView/).  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you try to write you own extension method to take bindingListView<T> as input, and I guess it expose that it uses List<T> internally so you could delegate to work to it.

Comment: I am actually trying to implement this, almost there :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `BindingListView<T>` project uses .NET Framework v2.0 and predates LINQ, it doesn't expose an `IEnumerable<T>` for you to query on.  Since it **does** implement non-generic `IEnumerable` and non-generic `IList`, you can use `Enumerable.Cast<TResult>` to convert the collection into a form suitable for use with LINQ.  However, this approach isn't that helpful because the `IEnumerable` that `AggregateBindingListView<T>` returns is an internal data structure with type `KeyValuePair<ListItemPair<T>, int>`.

To upgrade this project for convenient use with LINQ, the simplest approach might be to implement `IEnumerable<T>` on `AggregateBindingListView<T>`.  First add it to the declaration of the class:

```
public class AggregateBindingListView<T> : Component, IBindingListView, IList, IRaiseItemChangedEvents, ICancelAddNew, ITypedList, IEnumerable<T>
```

and then implement it at the end of the class definition:

```
#region IEnumerable<T> Members

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _sourceIndices.Count; i++)
        yield return _sourceIndices[i].Key.Item.Object;

}

#endregion
```

and now you can use LINQ directly on a `BindingListView<T>` instance like this:

```
// Create a view of the items
itemsView = new BindingListView<Item>(feed.Items);
var descriptions = itemsView.Select(t => t.Description);
```

Remember to upgrade all the projects from .NET Framework v2.0 to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and add `using System.Linq;` in order for this to work with your current project.

Comment: I forked the BindingListView on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/christianjunk/bindinglistview) and implemented your suggested changes. Thanks @RickSladkey

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what I got:
Here is my extension method :

```
public static class BindingViewListExtensions
{
  public static void Where<T>(this BindingListView<T> list, Func<T, bool> function)
  {
    // I am not sure I like this, but we know it is a List<T>
    var lists = list.DataSource as List<T>;

    foreach (var item in lists.Where<T>(function))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I got item {0}", item);
    }
  }
```

}

And then I used it like :

```
    List<string> source = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Thre" };

    BindingListView<string> binding = new BindingListView<string>(source);

    binding.Where<string>(xx => xx == "One");
```

I guess where in the extension method could return the found item.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, MBen.  However, this would only expose the Where<T> method and I'd like it to have full LINQ capabilities without making a new extension method as I need them.  Rick Sladkey's answer seems more along the lines of what I was looking for.  Thanks again, greatly appriciated!

Comment: well it was a good exercise for me :-).. I guess if you can change the code for the lib, it is better to go with Rick's solution.

Comment: I can indeed.  It's open source ;)

Comment: This is a great idea for when you don't have access to the code, though I might just extend the `AggregateBindingListView` if at all possible to provide all the LINQ functionality by adding `IEneumerable` methods.