# Need multiple views of same BindingList with sorting and filtering - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, collections

I know this is very similar to other questions that have been asked, and I have looked at them but in one way or another the solutions don't work for this specific scenario.

I have a collection of objects in a BindingList:

```
private BindingList<PathologyModel> _patientPathologies;
public BindingList<PathologyModel> PatientPathologies { get { return _patientPathologies; } }
```

This collection needs to be bound to different XamDataGrid controls (Infragistics' version of a DataGrid).  I need to use BindingList because I need to know when a user edits a particular item in the collection, which other types of collections don't seem to support.

I need the collection to be sorted,  so for now I just have to do this every time an item is added/removed from the list:

```
    private void Pathologies_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded || e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
        {
            _pathologies = new BindingList<PathologyModel>(_pathologies.OrderBy(x => x.Tooth.ToToothNumber()).ThenBy(x => x.DiagnosisDate).ToList());
        }
    }
```

It would be nice if this could be done automatically without the extra copying.  But that's not my biggest problem right now.

I need the different XamDataGrids to have different filtered views of this same collection, which currently I am achieving with this:

```
    public ICollectionView AllPathologies { get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PatientPathologies); } }

    public ICollectionView TodaysPathologies { get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PatientPathologies.Where(x => x.DiagnosisDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)); } }
```

This *almost* works... I say almost because the views are showing the correct data, but the final requirement is that I also need to track the CurrentItemChanged event, so that I can enable/disable certain operations depending on which record the user is on.  This works fine with the AllPathologies view,  but does not ever get raised with TodaysPathologies, I'm guessing because it gets a different copy of the collection source every time you access the property?  Strangely enough, the ListItem_Changed event still works properly against the original collection source.

I have tried making private CollectionViewSource objects to back the ICollectionView properties as I've seen in other articles, such as this:

```
private CollectionViewSource _todaysPathologies;
public ICollectionView TodaysPathologies { get { return _todaysPathologies.View; } }

...
_todaysPathologies = new CollectionViewSource{Source= _patientPathologies}.View;
```

But since the source is a BindingList I can't apply a filter predicate:

```
TodaysPathologies.CanFilter <--- false
```

So now I'm stuck.  I place my fate in your hands, dear StackOverflowers.

Comment: is your underlying source a datatable or dataview?

Comment: @blindmeis It is a BindingList

Comment: i think it does not work with bindinglist. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256559/enabling-linq-for-bindinglistviewt

Answer (score 0):

*"I need to know when a user edits a particular item in the collection, which other types of collections don't seem to support."*

This isn't entirely true. A Collection used within a Class that inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` would solve this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

I would recommend making an inner class in your window page. With a Property for each value and the editable properties would call the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event. You would then have a collection of these inner class objects. The inner class would represent a row in the grid.

Another way I've solved this before is to specify text column where users enter information:

In XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn //... Binding="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
         <Style TargetType="TextBox"/>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

In code:

```
private string value;
public string Value
        {
            get
            { return value; }
            set
            {
                this.value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
```

The inner class contains this `Value` Property as well as a reference to an object of the class I used to have a collection of.

Now I have a collection of objects of this inner class, which stores both. I use this to display info of the class and have an extra column to add a value. I then make a new object out of the old class information + this value.

If you've found this helpful and would like me to go into more detail, let me know. I would be more than happy to. That or someone will post :P

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding what you are solving by mirroring all of the properties of the original class to another one and trying to keep them in sync.  I already have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on all of the properties of the collected object.  AFAIK, BindingList is the only (WPF) collection type that will notify when an individual item's PropertyChanged notification fires - others like List and ObservableCollection, for example, only notify when the collection itself changes.

Comment: Ah I think this has helped me better understand your issue. Now, _"I need to know when a user edits a particular item in the collection"_. I assume you're getting the class object by casting the selected item. For the individual property, do you need to know the new value is for Validation purposes? If so I know solution for this.

Comment: The models in the collection are already validating and editing properly, my problem is creating multiple sorted & filtered views from a single source collection.